# ProfileCommon - where is it?

Tags: asp.net-profiles

I've added this to web config:

```
  <profile enabled="true" >

  <properties >

    <add name="Gender" type="string"/>
    <add name="Age" type="Int32"/>
  </properties>

  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Though, if I try to use ProfileCommon class, it doesn't find it. Shouldn't this have been generated when I uilt the project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using System.Web.Profile;
```

Did you import the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have the namespace in my page codebehind and my project is a WEB APPLICATION (NOT WEB SITE) but I don't get the ProfileCommon class.